# error 'Cannot invoke this function because the current host does not implement it'

Tags: powershell

Getting error

> Cannot invoke this function because the current host does not implement it

for a PowerShell code which deletes backup files older than 7 days.

Code used is:

```cs
Get-ChildItem -Path "filesystem::E:\MSSQL\DBMAINT\BACKUP\" -Recurse |
    Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)} |
    Remove-Item
```

Comment: Remove `filesystem::`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: thanks. It worked.